# Signals to child process

Tags: c, signals, fork, kill

I have to write a C program which creates a child and waits for a SIGHUP signal. After receiving that, it sends a signal to it's child. The child executes the default action of the received signal.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

void sigint();
void sighup();
pid_t pid, pid_parent;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        perror("fail1!");
        exit(1);
    }

    else if (pid == 0) {
        signal(SIGINT, sigint);
        while(1) pause();
        exit(1);
    }

    signal(SIGHUP, sighup);
    printf("PARENT's pid: %d\n", pid_parent = getpid());
    while(1) pause(); 

    return 0;
}

void sighup()
{
    signal(SIGHUP,sighup);
    kill(pid,SIGINT);
    printf("PARENT(%d): I received a SIGHUP. I'll send something to my child(%d).\n",getpid(),pid);
    printf("OK");
}

void sigint()
{
    signal(SIGINT,sigint);
    printf("CHILD: I received a SIGINT. I'll execute it.");
    signal(SIGINT,SIG_DFL);
}
```

Seems like it doesn't work after `kill(pid, SIGQUIT)`. And I really don't have ideas why.

Comment: What doesn't work? The child only prints something when it gets `SIGINT`, but you're sending `SIGQUIT`.

Comment: @Barmar I send SIGINT too, I send 2 signals in my program, but I posted here just one, deleted the wrong line there by accident. I'm sorry.

Comment: I reproduced the problem. I thought it might be output buffering, because you don't have `\n` at the end of the child's message, but adding that didn't help.

Comment: @Barmar The interesting thing is, that my function prints the line with parent's message, but the next one, "printf("OK")" doesn't get printed. Thank you. :)

Comment: Add a newline to it. Terminal output is line-buffered.

Comment: Don't `printf` in a signal handler. `man 7 signal` for async-signal-safe functions.